# How to convert void* to std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >*?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, stl, new-operator

The some part of my code is given below. 
Here m_out defined like: `static_cast<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >* m_out;`

The problem is in the given line `m_out->push_back(row);` . I get the "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and when I debug I found that the cause in the given line above.
I assume that, this is due to the fact that for m_out does not allocate memory. If so, how can I allocate memory for given two dimensional vector ?

```
int some_space::database::callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** col_name)
 {
     if(m_out != 0) {
         m_out->clear();
     }   
     m_out = static_cast<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >*>(data);
     std::vector<std::string> row;
     for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i){
         row.push_back(argv[i] ? argv[i] : "(NULL)");
     }
     m_out->push_back(row);
     return 0;
 }
```

Thanks All. I solved my problem. I changed code like this.
Now m_out is a variable and not a pointer `static_cast<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > m_out;`.

```
int some_space::database::callback(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** col_name)
 {
    if(m_out.size() != 0) {
        m_out.clear();
    }   
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) { 
        m_out.push_back(std::vector< std::string >());
     }   
     for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
         m_out[i].push_back(std::string( (char *)argv[i] ? argv[i] : "(NULL)"));
     }   
     return 0;
 }
```

And this works fine :)

Comment: You don't say what error you get...

Comment: What is `m_out`? Where is your minimal testcase?

Comment: I get "segmentation fault" on the line: m_out->push_back(row);

Comment: m_out is static_cast<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >* m_out;

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with how you create row, so m_out must be null.

Answer (score 0):

With the cast you claim that `data` points to a vector. If that's not true this won't work.

You have to created a vector first and make sure a pointer to it will be passed as `data` (wherever that's coming from). For example it could look similar to this:

```
db.set_callback_data(new std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >);
```

Comment: I hope it wouldn't look like that as that is a leak... but I get that it's an example.

Comment: Well what is OP asking for is either a leak or unitialized memory access ;)

Comment: @EdS. Not necessarily - the callback saves the pointer in `m_out`, so it could be freed later.  Still, I agree it's a pretty bad way to manage object lifetimes.

Comment: Sorry, you're right; didn't notice that it wasn't local to the function. Of course, his design is just asking for trouble.